# How to reverse integers using while or for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, counter

Sorry, I am new to java. I want to create a program that displays reversed integers using any kind of loop. For example I would ask user to enter a positive integer and then I would return reversed input to the user. So far this is the closest I got, but I get the count of the string in reverse and not the values that were captured.

```
String number;

for (int c = number.length(); c >= 0; c--) {
    System.out.print(c);
}
```

Comment: Please post an example input, and the desired output.

Comment: @Berger - Why?  It's clear from the question.  If the input is 1234, the output should be 4321.

Comment: @Jared - do you know about the `charAt` method of the `String` class?

Comment: @David Wallace Okay, the "reversed integer" part puzzled me :)

Answer (score 2):

```
String number;

for (int c = number.length() - 1; c >= 0; c--){
    System.out.print(number.charAt(c));
}
```

This should do the trick. `c` is the position in your string, use it to print the `char` at that position.
(Also, remember it's `String`, not string. Same for `System`)

Edit: Oops, forgot to add the "-1" in number.length()

Answer (score 2):

You can try something likewise(either of way),

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String number = "hello";

        for (int c = number.length()-1; c >= 0; c--)
        {
            System.out.print(number.charAt(c));
        }
        // At the end output is : olleh

        System.out.println();
        // Or another way is, using StringBuffer
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Hello String");
        System.out.println(sb.reverse()); //Output :- gnirtS olleH

    }
```

Comment: The gif is completely unnecessary!

Comment: @weston Why is it unnecessary? Does it decrease value of the whole answer? It even weighs ~300 kB so it will work good with poor internet connection.

Comment: "Why is it unnecessary?" Because it shows you running the code!

Comment: "Does it decrease value of the whole answer?" Yes, because it is a repeat of the code, and seeing it run adds nothing. I think anything that adds nothing, can only take away. Best answers are **succinct**.

Comment: It could be worse.  There could be sound effects.

Comment: @DavidWallace what you mean ? may i know better than this which will hone my skill up ?thanks